# How to run bash script after webpack build in npm

Tags: bash, npm, webpack

I have having trouble chaining scripts in npm. I am using webpack, running a build script then would like to run a bash file after. Both commands are working, but not if chaining them.

In my package.json I have this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-staging": "webpack --config webpack-staging.config.js -p || ./build-staging.sh"
  },
```

If I run `npm run build-staging` it webpack runs the build and works fine. It does not run my `build-staing.sh` however. If I manually run this bash file it runs, so my issue is having it chain and run after the webpack script is finished. I've seen that the pipe `||` should do this, but no luck.

Am I doing the pipe wrong, or does the bash script not run because webpack does not 'kill' the script once finished? I am not able to run any more commands unless I use Crtl+C, maybe that's the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`||` is only used to run a program if the previous command failed (returned a non-zero status).

```
$ bash -c "exit 0" || echo "This won't run"
$ bash -c "exit 1" || echo "This will run"
This will run
$
```

If you want your second script to run regardless, you could use

```
"scripts": {
    "build-staging": "webpack --config webpack-staging.config.js -p ; ./build-staging.sh"
  },
```

Or if you only want it to run on success (which is more likely), you could use `&&` instead of `||`.  Note that `;` may not be supported by your platform.  As mentioned in the comments, `;` doesn't work on Windows, but `&&` does.

Comment: This should be edited to reflect the fact that `;` doesn't work on windows. `&&` does.

Comment: Yep, `||` was my problem. `&&` fixed it.